# Not getting all the keys of nested object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to fetch all the keys of one nested object using Javascript but as per my code its not working as expected. I am explaining my code below.

```js
let jsonObj = {
    "service":[
        {
            "name":"restservice",
            "device":"xr-1",
            "interface-port":"0/0/2/3",
            "interface-description":"uBot testing for NSO REST",
            "addr":"10.10.1.3/24",
            "mtu":1024
        }
    ],
    "person": {
    "male": {
      "name": "infinitbility"
    },
    "female": {
      "name": "aguidehub"
    }
  }
}

const getNestedKeys = (data, keys) => {
  if(!(data instanceof Array) && typeof data == 'object'){
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
      keys.push(key);
      const value = data[key];
      if(typeof value === 'object' && !(value instanceof Array)){
         getNestedKeys(value, keys);
      }
   });
  }
  return keys
}
let result = getNestedKeys(jsonObj, []);

console.log('result', result);
```

Here I am not getting the keys present inside the `service` array. I need to search all the keys present inside one nested object using Javascript.

Comment: Please take note that `let jsonObj` means you do not have JSON, you have a normal JS object.

Comment: In both places you are checking that the property you are currently handling is not `instanceof Array` - but `service` _is_ an array?

Comment: add an `else if(Array.isArray(value))` after the second if and inside that `value.forEach(val => getNestedKeys(val, keys))` . someting like this?

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple items in the array?

Comment: in case need to remove duplicates from the final result `[...new Set(result)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this

```js
const readAllKeys = obj => {
  if(typeof obj !== 'object'){
    return []
  }
  if(Array.isArray(obj)){
    return obj.flatMap(readAllKeys)
  }
  
  return [...Object.keys(obj), ...Object.values(obj).flatMap(readAllKeys)]
}


let jsonObj = {
    "service":[
        {
            "name":"restservice",
            "device":"xr-1",
            "interface-port":"0/0/2/3",
            "interface-description":"uBot testing for NSO REST",
            "addr":"10.10.1.3/24",
            "mtu":1024
        }
    ],
    "person": {
    "male": {
      "name": "infinitbility"
    },
    "female": {
      "name": "aguidehub"
    }
  }
}

console.log(readAllKeys(jsonObj))
```

Comment: Note: If there are multiple entries in the array, the key is added multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for it to work with "service" key which is an array, but your code explicitly checks type and if it's array it just ignores it. Here is the code adjusted to work with array too.

```js
let jsonObj = {
    "service":[
        {
            "name":"restservice",
            "device":"xr-1",
            "interface-port":"0/0/2/3",
            "interface-description":"uBot testing for NSO REST",
            "addr":"10.10.1.3/24",
            "mtu":1024
        }
    ],
    "person": {
    "male": {
      "name": "infinitbility"
    },
    "female": {
      "name": "aguidehub"
    }
  }
}

const getNestedKeys = (data, keys) => {
  if(data instanceof Array) {
      data.forEach(value => {
          getNestedKeys (value, keys);
      });
  }

  if(!(data instanceof Array) && typeof data == 'object'){
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
      keys.push(key);
      const value = data[key];
      if(typeof value === 'object'){
         getNestedKeys(value, keys);
      }
   });
  }
  return keys
}
let result = getNestedKeys(jsonObj, []);

console.log('result', result);
```